# How can I redirect user after they login properly?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, firebase-authentication, react-router-dom

I am building an app that uses react and firebase. I created a login component, where it sets the state "isLoggedIn" to true after they log in and redirects the user to the main page. The problem is that the state is false by default then takes time to set, so when you refresh the main page, you can see the login page briefly. Do I change my router redirect code or set the state differently?

Here is my code:

```
 const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false)

 onAuthStateChanged(auth,  (currentUser) => {
    setIsLoggedIn(currentUser)
})

return (
    <Router>
        {isLoggedIn ? <Redirect to="/home" /> : <Redirect to="/login" />}
        <Route path="/home" component={SongList} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Auth} />
    </Router>
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` v5 the common pattern is to create a custom route component that handles the auth state, *even when it's pending*. Create an `AuthRoute` component that starts from an indeterminant state and don't render the route's component *or* the redirect until you have authentication confirmation.

Example:

```
const AuthRoute = props => {
  const location = useLocation();

  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(); // <-- neither true nor false

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth,  (currentUser) => {
      setIsLoggedIn(currentUser); // sets user object or null
    });

    return unsubscribe; // <-- cleanup auth subscription!
  }, []);

  if (isLoggedIn === undefined) return null; // <-- or loading indicator, etc...
  
  return isLoggedIn ? (
    <Route {...props} />
  ) : (
    <Redirect
      to={{
        pathname: "/login",
        state: { location }, // <-- pass current location
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Usage:

```
<Router>
  <Switch> // <-- match & render a single route
    <AuthRoute path="/home" component={SongList} />
    <Route path="/login" component={Auth} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

In the `Auth` component access the passed `location` from route state and after a successful login you can redirect users back to the route they were originally attempting to access.

```
const { state } = useLocation();
const history = useHistory();

...

// successful login, redirect back to route, or home if undefined
history.replace(state.location?.pathname ?? "/home")
```

Having each "instance" of a `PrivateRoute` maintaining its own state though you'll be doing a lot of auth checks. From here you may want to implement an `AuthProvider` React context component that stores the `isLoggedIn` state and each `PrivateRoute` component subscribes to the context value. This way after a user logs in the app can hold on to this state and not need to recheck/fetch it each time a protected route is accessed.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply Mr. Drew. I tried using your code, I made the AuthRoute component, however the redirect isn't working. I am confused on the props we pass into the AuthRouter, we pass the path and component then spread it, I am unfamiliar with this syntax? I do not know how the AuthRoute component works with my App.js to redirect the user.

Comment: @KaiTheGuy Yes, the props passed to `AuthRoute` are the props normally passed to a `Route` component, they are indeed all passed through (spread syntax) to the rendered `Route` component. What is the value of the `isLoggedIn` state in the case that a user is *not* authenticated via the firebase auth listener?

Comment: The state when the user isn't authenticated says null when I run console.log(isLoggedIn). When I login in successfully it doesn't redirect, but if i change the route manually (in the search-bar) then it works properly. And the state only changes when I manually change the route, is this how it is supposed to work?

Comment: @KaiTheGuy Oh, I see, it sounds like `null` is a valid `currentUser` value returned from Firebase if there is no authenticated user. If this is the case then the "indeterminate" state needs to be something else that isn't a valid auth state. `undefined` make work here then. I'll update.

Comment: I'm sorry for all the questions but everything is working perfectly except the user still isn't redirected after they log in successfully.

Comment: @KaiTheGuy No worries. Can you clarify what you mean by "isn't redirected after they log in successfully"? Do you mean *after* they are redirected to the "/login" path and log in, you want them redirected back to this route/path?

Comment: Okay so the user is supposed to get this login screen component (Auth) when they first visit the site, after they login they can have access to the main application. However when they are authenticated on the Auth component, by pressing "log in" or "sign up", they are not redirected to the main page (SongList) path="/home"

Comment: @KaiTheGuy I updated with a brief explanation for redirecting back to a location after authenticating.